# Email doesn't show in "Sent" folder immediately after sending

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Whenever I send an email from Outlook and I immediately go to review it in the Sent folder, the email is not available.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I assume Outlook 2007 for Windows (XP/Vista/7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't have it set up to store a copy in your Sent Items?

The settings may depend on your account settings (Exchange/imap/pop3 what not)

[From the Office.Microsoft pages:](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA101642161033.aspx)

> **Change where sent messages are saved when using an IMAP e-mail account**
>
> In Microsoft Office Outlook 2007, you
>   can specify where sent items are saved
>   for your IMAP e-mail account. For
>   example, if you are at work and add a
>   personal e-mail account to Outlook,
>   you can configure your sent items to
>   be saved in the Sent Items folder of
>   the data file or in a Personal Folders
>   file (.pst) for your personal account.
>
> *NOTE   The first time you send an e-mail message with your IMAP account,
>   you are prompted to choose the folder
>   where you want sent items saved.*
>
> - On the Tools menu, click Account Settings.
> - Select an e-mail account that is not an Exchange account, and then click
>     Change.
> - Click More Settings.
> - In the Internet E-mail Settings dialog box, click the Folders tab.
>
>   [image]
> - To choose a custom folder for saving your sent items, click Choose
>     an existing folder or create a new
>     folder to save your sent items for
>     this account in.
> - Click a folder to save the sent items in, or click New Folder.
>
> *By default, the sent messages from all your accounts are saved in the
>   default Sent Items folder in Outlook.
>   If you have an Exchange account in
>   your Outlook profile, the default
>   folder is Sent Items in your Exchange
>   mailbox.*
>
> - Click Choose an existing folder or create a new folder to save your sent
>     items for this account in, expand the
>     folder list, and then click a folder.
>     Usually, you choose Sent Items in the
>     data file for the account that you
>     selected.
>
>   *NOTE   You should first make sure
>     that you are subscribed to the Sent
>     Items folder so that it will appear in
>     the Internet E-mail Settings dialog
>     box as described in step 4. For
>     information about how to subscribe to
>     IMAP account folders, see the See Also
>     section.*

Comment: this does not works for outlook 2010 with exchange account. :(
The "Folders" tab isn't there at all.

Comment: That´s very well possible, they have moved quite a bit

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2010

> Go to **File > Account Settings** and select the account & click on
>   **Change**. Click on **More Settings** then **Sent Items** tab. Then change from **Save sent items in the following folder on the server**,
>   to **Save sent items in the sent items folder on this computer**

This will indeed keep a copy of the sent mail on the computer, but this folder is not synced using IMAP.